# rel="noopener noreferrer" get automatically added on other content when we add new link with target equals to blank in RTE

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor

Sitecore 8.2 update 4

We've been editing some pages, and noticing that `rel="noopener noreferrer"` get's added into text. I understand that, it's good to have it added to `_blank` links. But it's being auto-added in text blocks as well when editing.

Ex- I open an RTE field and add new link using "HyperLink Manager" and choose target as a blank. Now save the item and again open RTE field what it did that it added a `rel="noopener noreferrer"` on link, as well as on above text that is in RTE.
[image]

I found a property in `Sitecore.config` called "`ProtectExternalLinksWithBlankTarget`" by disabling this "noopener noreferrer" feature is disabled but is there any other way to use this feature correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug.I raised a ticket to Sitecore support and they replied that it is a bug and it already resolved in Sitecore 8.2 update 6

So you have two choices here -

1. Upgrade your solution on Sitecore 8.2 update 6 or
2. Raised a support ticket on Sitecore support portal and they will provide you the fix/patch.

Comment: Remember to update answer with the patch number once received.

Comment: we have sitecore 9.0 and issue is still there.

Comment: Can you please share patch number or bug number so we can get the patch from Sitecore?

Comment: Yes, @simone it is also a bug in Sitecore 9 initial release

Comment: @Nirlep The bug number is 175841

Answer (score 5):

#### You should leave it as is.

`target="_blank"` is a security vulnerability. In previous versions, you had to fix this yourself but in Sitecore 8.2 onwards, this is the default behaviour.

More information here: [Adding rel=”noopener” to Sitecore](https://mikael.com/2017/07/adding-relnoopener-to-sitecore/)

Edited to add: Your clarified behaviour, however, is clearly a bug and should be taken to Sitecore Support.

Comment: Did you get anything from Sitecore regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has created a KB article for this issue which can be found [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/339618) It also contains a link do download the [patch](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.223855/releases)

I ran into this issue with 9.0.1 and the Sitecore patch fixed the issue.